# java.lang.outofmemoryerror exception?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, out-of-memory

I have trouble with my android project, I did not touch anything and suddenly my app stopped working because of this error. Do you have some idea about what is happening? The error is this:

```
10-30 22:53:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(19137): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1210
10-30 22:53:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(19137): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-30 22:53:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(19137):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
10-30 22:53:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(19137):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
10-30 22:53:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(19137):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:549)
10-30 22:53:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(19137):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
10-30 22:53:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(19137):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
10-30 22:53:38.246: E/AndroidRuntime(19137):    at    com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:85)
```

please help me!!

Comment: Whatever you have stored on the disk has become too large to fit in the memory at once?

Comment: Hi jony, Have you got the solution. I am also having same exception. Can you share the solution, please ?

Comment: Will you please your code here for more understanding?

Comment: may be this [issue][1] can help you!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095909/volley-out-of-memory-error-weird-allocation-attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-If the problem is due to Bitmaps then use

> **Lazy Imageloader** for Bitmaps in listviews

-Make sure you dnt have too much work in its background task.

-And if possible please post your code from where you are getting this issue so we can also learn from it . THanks! :)

Comment: I am using UNiversal Image loader for loading images in my feedlist but I am getting at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316) error.I am using a viewpager with five fragments.What can be the reason behind this.

Answer (score 5):

[Looks like a fix for this went in June 24th](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/0e406003b5d434d8f16d7d6ad97d446060b788e6) .

Comment: As far as I can see it isn't released yet although it looks like a fix.

Answer (score 2):

This thing can be an easy fix for this

just add this line in your application tag in manifest file

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

like this

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    ......
```

Answer (score 2):

you can detect you memory leaks from **Memory analyzer in eclipse** which is taking much space and optimize your code by that