# OOM error in volley diskbased cache

Tags: android, android-volley, image-loading

I have below OOM error on android i have used volley library for network image loading in android.

```
   10-15 11:48:01.690: E/AndroidRuntime(22735): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   10-15 11:48:01.690: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):     at      com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:322)
  10-15 11:48:01.690: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):  at  com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:532)
  10-15 11:48:01.690: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:554)
  10-15 11:48:01.690: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:398)
  10-15 11:48:01.690: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:156)
  10-15 11:48:01.690: E/AndroidRuntime(22735):  at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095909/volley-out-of-memory-error-weird-allocation-attempt

Comment: When shall i clear the cache and how to clear