# How to prevent Volley to load all response in to memory

Tags: android, stream, network-programming, android-volley

I have used DefaultHttpClient in my app to make network operation and used stream parser to parse large responses
Now I want to use Volley to simplify and reduce my code size

But Volley loads all response in Memory which may raise OutOfMemory issue in my case
It is asynchronous networking library and automatically gets back  parsed response to main thread 
I don't want to load all response in memory
So I want to know how to use volley to implement stream parsing

Thanks...

Comment: Maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095909/volley-out-of-memory-error-weird-allocation-attempt