# OutOfMemoryError in using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

when i using volley in my app, sometime it crash, the log is

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:549)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
```

any ideas is thankful

Comment: search google or stackoverflow for "android memory leak" and you get the answer. i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks

Comment: are using LRUcache ? maybe you need to increase the memory allocation!

Comment: yeah,i have been used lrucache? how do i increase the memory allocation,i used the system memory's 1/4,am i ok

Comment: This is a known issue with Volley. See more at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42196956/901597